# Value of a json key is another valid json itsef. Can this value be parsed as a String instead of parsing the inner json as json?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following code which should parse a simple json as follows:

```
{"jsonTest":
    {"innerKey":"innerValue"}
}
```

Here, the value of 'jsonTest' is a json object. 
Question : Can this JSON be parsed (using jackson) and retrieve the value of 'jsonTest' as a simple String? In other words, is there a way to ask the parser not to parse the inner json object?

here is what I tried so far. This results in a parsing exception

```
 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
```

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonParserTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = "{\"jsonTest\":{\"innerKey\":\"innerValue\"}}";
       TestJson js = mapper.readValue(json, TestJson.class);
       System.out.println(js.getJsonTest());
    }

}

class TestJson {

    private String jsonTest;

    public String getJsonTest() {
        return jsonTest;
    }

    public void setJsonTest(String jsonTest) {
        this.jsonTest = jsonTest;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JsonNode for this. Just change your TestJson class:

```
class TestJson {

    private JsonNode jsonTest;

    public JsonNode getJsonTest() {
        return jsonTest;
    }

    public void setJsonTest(JsonNode jsonTest) {
        this.jsonTest = jsonTest;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"innerKey":"innerValue"}
```

Also you can do it just using the JsonNode without the TestJson class. 
Use the following mapper.readTree method:

```
 JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
 System.out.println(jsonNode.get("jsonTest").toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create structure to deseralize that json. It could be something like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class TestJson {
    JsonTest jsonTest;
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    private static class JsonTest {
       String innerKey;
  }
}
```